# How can I convert bash's command substitution and pipe to an Applescript?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, applescript, sh

I need help converting this simple shell script to an apple script.

The point being because it is to be used in an Automator workflow, and so I need the Terminal window to be open, which cannot be done using a shell script.

The shell script is as follows:

```
java -classpath `dirname "$1"` `basename "$1" | sed "s/.class//g"`
```

This gets the location of the file, and then the name of the file, and then strips away the file extension of ".class", and then runs it using the Java command. So for example it would generate the following command:

```
java -classpath /users/desktop/ filename
```

I need to convert this command so that it works with Applescript so that I can then see the application run in the Terminal window. It would start like the following:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do shell script "java -classpath path/to/ file"
    end tell
end run
```

How can I port the text transformation to Applescript?

Answer (score 2):

The only issue I'm seeing (right now) is to change `do shell script` to `do script`. Other than that, you've started it correctly. I'm assuming you want to pass (a) file reference(s) to the shell script. It's fairly simple...

```
set these_files to (choose file with multiple selections allowed)
repeat with this_file in these_files
    tell application "Finder" to if the name extension of this_file is "class" then my do_shell_script(this_file)
end repeat

on do_shell_script(this_file)
    tell application "Terminal" to activate --makes 'Terminal' the frontmost application
    --'do shell script ...' goes here
    --To refer to a file/folder for a 'do shell script', do something like the command below...
    --do shell script "mdls -name kMDItemLastUsedDate " & quoted form of the POSIX path of this_file
end do_shell_script
```

Comment: Remember to use the `quoted form of` the posix path

Comment: @Flambino WOW I didn't see that. Thanks I'll fix it. :D

Answer (score -1):

I don't know AppleScript at all, but I suppose you could simply call your existing shell script in the `do shell script` line, instead of trying to redo the string manipulation in AppleScript.

Note:
It looks like you want to be able to invoke Java classes by click (or drag-n-drop or such). Your method will only work for classes in the anonymous package, i.e. without any `package ...;` declaration in the beginning of the source code. For others, you might try to find out in which package they are. I have no idea how to do this. Distributable programs should be in jar archives, anyway, where you should be able to start it with `java -jar ...`.)